# calling same function on different buttons not loaded yet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I can not get this to work for every button and I cannot find anything explaining why. I guessing it is something small that I am missing

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // delete the selected row from the database
  $(document).on('click', '#business-area-delete-button', { model: "BusinessArea" }, deleteRow);
  $(document).on('click', '#business-type-delete-button', { model: "BusinessType" }, deleteRow);
  $(document).on('click', '#client-delete-button', { model: "Client" }, deleteRow);
  $(document).on('click', '#client-type-delete-button', { model: "ClientType" }, deleteRow);
  $(document).on('click', '#communication-channel-type', { model: "CommunicationChannelType" }, deleteRow);
  $(document).on('click', '#parameter-type-delete-button', { model: "ParameterType" }, deleteRow);
  $(document).on('click', '#validation-method-delete-button', { model: "ValidationMethod" }, deleteRow);
}
```

the event

```
function deleteRow(event){
  $.ajax(
    {
      type:'POST',
      data: { id: $(".delete-row").attr("id") },
      url:"/mysite/admin/delete" + event.data.model,
      success:function(data,textStatus){
        $('#main-content').html(data);
      },
      error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){
       jQuery('#alerts').html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
      },
      complete:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus){
        placeAlerts()
      }
    }
   );
   return false
};
```

This works only for a the button with id validation-method-delete-button. I use document and not the button its self because the button is contained in a template that is loaded later via ajax.

I have this working for a similar function that is selecting a row in a table however I am not attempting to pass data in that scenario.

Comment: Is it a copying error that you don't close the document-ready function? In any case I'd try to delete the last row to figure out if now, another button starts to work, possibly the last one.

Comment: So, what part of your application does not work? Do you get any errors in the console? What's the difference from #validation-method-delete-button to the other button, what is the difference to the similar function?

Comment: You don't need to put those in ready()

Answer (score 1):

If your buttons not loaded yet, try to use `live` instead `on`

Comment: on() will work with buttons that aren't in the DOM yet. I've used it plenty of times.

Answer (score 0):

It was something very small as I suspected. Darn typos! Lol. Either way might as well keep this constructive as I am sure other people may run into the same issue.

So

Is live() better to use then on() (They both work).

Comment: As `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 (http://api.jquery.com/live/), it would be better to use `.on()` (until they deprecate that as well... :) ) Also, please indicate in your self answer, where the typo was.

Comment: Good to know. The typo was in my html documents I accidentally copy/pasted the # into my button ids. The posted code is valid.